# Print last modified date only on posts

Tags: php, functions, filters, date, date-time

I'm printing the last modified date via functions.php with the following code

```
function wpb_last_updated_date( $content ) {
    $u_time = get_the_time('U'); 
    $u_modified_time = get_the_modified_time('U'); 
    if ($u_modified_time >= $u_time + 86400) { 
        $updated_date = get_the_modified_time('F jS, Y');
        $updated_time = get_the_modified_time('h:i a'); 
        $custom_content .= '<p class="last-updated">Last updated on '. $updated_date . ' at '. $updated_time .'</p>';  
    } 

    $custom_content .= $content;
    return $custom_content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpb_last_updated_date' );
```

The problem is that it appears on pages too, but I need to appear only on posts. Is there an `if` command to choose only blog posts?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the post type with `get_post_type()`. You only want to display the content if the value is `post`:

```
function wpb_last_updated_date( $content ) {
    $u_time          = get_the_time( 'U' ); 
    $u_modified_time = get_the_modified_time( 'U' ); 

    if ( get_post_type() === 'post' ) {
        if ( $u_modified_time >= $u_time + 86400) { 
            $updated_date   = get_the_modified_time( 'F jS, Y' );
            $updated_time   = get_the_modified_time( 'h:i a' ); 
            $custom_content = '<p class="last-updated">Last updated on '. $updated_date . ' at '. $updated_time .'</p>';
        }
    }

    $custom_content .= $content;

    return $custom_content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpb_last_updated_date' );
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to check, if current post is a post and not a page:

```
function wpb_last_updated_date( $content ) {
    if ( 'post' != get_post_type() ) return $content;

    $u_time = get_the_time('U'); 
    $u_modified_time = get_the_modified_time('U'); 
    if ($u_modified_time >= $u_time + 86400) { 
        $updated_date = get_the_modified_time('F jS, Y');
        $updated_time = get_the_modified_time('h:i a'); 
        $custom_content .= '<p class="last-updated">Last updated on '. $updated_date . ' at '. $updated_time .'</p>';  
    } 

    $custom_content .= $content;
    return $custom_content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpb_last_updated_date' );
```

Comment: `get_the_ID()` is redundant here. `get_post_type()` checks the same global post that `get_the_ID()` does.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Yup, you're right. Good catch.